# Why NN doesn't predict well?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Please help me to understand why predict doesn't work correct, when train-test accuracy is 0.97.

Is it from data, or network should be changed?

Input data are 32500 (5 gesture with 6500 images) RGB images with 640*480 pixels.

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/835Cw.jpg)

Images loaded and resized IMG_WIDTH = 100, IMG_HEIGHT = 77.
Here's the function which load, resized images and return np.array.

```
def load_data(data_dir):
"""
Load image data from directory `data_dir`.
Assume `data_dir` has one directory named after each category, numbered
0 through NUM_CATEGORIES - 1. Inside each category directory will be some
number of image files.
Return tuple `(images, labels)`. `images` should be a list of all
of the images in the data directory, where each image is formatted as a
numpy ndarray with dimensions IMG_WIDTH x IMG_HEIGHT x 3. `labels` should
be a list of integer labels, representing the categories for each of the
corresponding `images`.
"""
images = []
labels = []

for dir in range(0, NUM_CATEGORIES):
    # get path for each gesture 
    d = os.path.join(data_dir, f"{str(dir)}")
        # os.listdir(d) return the list of all names of images in that folder
        for image_path in os.listdir(d):
            # get the full path of specific image 
            full_path = os.path.join(data_dir, f"{str(dir)}", image_path)
            # Returns an image that is loaded from the specified file
            image = cv2.imread(full_path)       
            # get dimension for each image
            dim = (100, 77)
            # resized the image
            image_resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            
            # add image and their directory name to images and labels list
            images.append(image_resized)
            labels.append(dir)
    
    return images, labels
```

Here's my model.

```
def get_model():
"""
Returns a compiled convolutional neural network model. Assume that the
`input_shape` of the first layer is `(IMG_WIDTH=100, IMG_HEIGHT=77, 3)`.
The output layer should have `NUM_GESTURE = 5` units, one for each category.
"""
# Create a convolutional neural network
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
    # Convolutional layer. Learn 32 filters using a 3x3 kernel
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3)
    ),
    # Max-pooling layer, using 2x2 pool size
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3)
    ),
    # Max-pooling layer, using 2x2 pool size
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=((IMG_WIDTH), (IMG_HEIGHT), 3)
    ),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        128, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=((IMG_WIDTH), (IMG_HEIGHT), 3)
    ),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    # Add a hidden layer with dropout
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    # Add an output layer with output units for all 5 gestures
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])



 # Train neural network
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    return model

labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
np.array(images), np.array(labels), test_size=0.4)
model = get_model()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
```

The result is 0.97.
[fit result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhnuX.png)

From video I save the image and want to real time predict the hand gesture.

```
GESTURE = {0:"ok", 1:"down", 2:"up", 3:"palm", 4:"l"}
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture the video frame
    ret, img = video.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    # to flip the video with 180 degree 
    image = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    
    # save image for prediction
    image = cv2.imwrite('Frame'+str(0)+'.jpg', image)
    image_addr = "Frame0.jpg"
    image = cv2.imread(image_addr)
    
    dim = (100,77)
    
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_addr, target_size=dim)
    # Converts a PIL Image instance to a Numpy array. Return a 3D Numpy array.
    input_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
    # Convert single image to a batch.
    input_arr = np.array([input_arr])
    input_arr = input_arr.astype('float32')/255
    # Generates output predictions for the input samples. Return Numpy array(s) of predictions.
    predictions = model.predict(input_arr)
    # Return the index_array of the maximum values along an axis.
    pre_class = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
    # for writing in the video
    text = GESTURE[pre_class[0]]
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    image = cv2.flip(img, 1)

    cv2.putText(image, 
            text, 
            (50, 50), 
            font, 2, 
            (0, 0, 0), 
            2, 
            cv2.LINE_4)
            
    cv2.imshow('video', image)


    # the 'q' button is set as the
    # quitting button you may use any
    # desired button of your choice

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == ord('q'):
            break

video.release()       
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[github link](https://github.com/arpharutyunyan/hand_detection.git)

Comment: if with "doesnt predict well" you mean your score from the test set is low its probably overfitting

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert, but typically when you perform well on the training data and the testing data "`The result is 0.97`", but perform poorly on new end-user data, it is because there is a data-mismatch (although it could possibly be overfitting).

As in, the data you trained and tested on is so different (pixel values, probability distribution of pixels, or unseen differences that are noticable to the model) that the model could not generalize to it and performed badly.

It is good practice to use the same data you would use in production/final-product as a test set. Andrew Ng uses this dataset split(this is applicable if you have enough data):

From the training data:

- Training Set
- Train-Dev (same as Validation, I think) Set

From the end-product data:

- Development Set
- Test Set

You can check this post for more information regarding why: https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/split/

Answer (score 0):

Your preprocess in training step mismatch with preprocess in predict step:
input_arr = input_arr.astype('float32')/255